# How to execute Windows CLI commands in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line, windows-console, backticks

I have a file located in the directory "C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe" but when I write the command `` `C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe `` in single qoutes(which I am not able to display in this box), used for executing the commands in Ruby, I am not able to do so and the error that I recieve is No file or Directory found. I have tried replacing "\" with "//" and "\" but nothing seems to work. I have also used system, IO.popen and exec commands but all efforts are in vain. Also exec commands makes the program to make an exit which I don't want to happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you bean "backtick" instead of "single quotes", but I'm not going to edit your question unless you confirm that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
`"C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe"`
```

or

```
`exec "C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe"`
```

or whatever in qoutes

Comment: main idea is to wrap the path into quotes. I am not familiar with Windows so there can be any other restrictions.

Comment: Don't know if the file I am working with has some constraints to work in a Ruby program or the way I am specifying the path of the file is incorrect but the thing is not working for me... But the method that you have told is correct!!!

Answer (score 8):

The backtick environment is like double-quotes, so backslash are used for escaping.  Further, Ruby will interpret the spaces as separating command-line arguments, so you need to quote the entire thing:

```
`"C:\\Documents and Settings\\test.exe"`
```

Another option is to use `system` and force a second argument.  If `system` gets more than one argument, it treats the first argument as the path to the command to execute and you don't need to quote the command:

```
system('C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe','')
```

Note the use of *single* quotes, so we don't have escape the backslashes.

Of course, this won't get you the standard out/error, so if you are on Ruby 1.9.2, you can use the awesomely handy `Open3` library, which works like `system`, but gives you more information about the process you just ran:

```
require 'open3'

stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3('C:\Documents and Settings\test.exe','')

puts stdout # => string containing standard output of your command
puts stderr # => string containing standard ERROR of your command
if status.success?
  puts "It worked!"
else
  puts "OH NOES! Got exit code #{status.exitstatus}"
end
```

Comment: undefined method `capture3' for Open3:Module (NoMethodError) with ruby 1.8.7