# Why is this csc task not working in Albacore?

Tags: ruby, cmd, albacore

I wrote the following `csc` task for compiling some C# source code using Ruby/Rake/Albacore.

```
csc :build do |csc|
  csc.command = 'csc.exe'
  csc.compile FileList['MyFolder/*.cs']
  csc.output = 'F:My.dll'
  csc.target = :library
end
```

And I got this "no method" error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `csc' for main:Object

I tried calling the command directly in my shell

```
cmd> csc.exe /target:library /out:F:My.dll /warn:0 /nologo /debug MyFolder/*.cs
```

And using the Ruby shell execute method

```
system('csc.exe /target:library /out:F:My.dll /warn:0 /nologo /debug MyFolder/*.cs')
```

And I get these errors!

> error CS2001: Source file '\target:library' could not be found
>   error CS2001: Source file 'F:My.dll' could not be found
>   error CS2001: Source file '\warn:0' could not be found
>   error CS2001: Source file '\nologo' could not be found
>   error CS2001: Source file '\debug' could not be found

I changed the Ruby shell execute method to use the args array parameter

```
system('csc.exe', '/target:library', '/out:F:My.dll', '/warn:0', '/nologo', '/debug', 'MyFolder/*.cs')
```

And got a different path error

> error CS1504: Source file 'MyFolder\my.cs' could not be opened ('The system cannot find the file specified. ')

I don't have any idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute Windows CLI commands in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531498/how-to-execute-windows-cli-commands-in-ruby)

Comment: I can`t call cmd with params, I have errors: error CS2001: Source file '\target:library' could not be found error...

Comment: @Badfishmaan then please update the question's description with a more-complete explanation of the problem.  Feel free to *keep updating it as you learn more*.  That's how this process works

Comment: Thank you, @NewAlexandria, I updated my question's description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I'm certain that you're using the wrong version of Albacore. The `csc` method was defined in the global scope in Albacore 1.0 and does not exist at all in Albacore 2.0. That's why you're seeing this error.

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'csc' for main:Object

You probably have an optimistic dependency in your Gemfile

```
gem "albacore"
```

or used the unversioned gem install command

```
$ gem install albacore
```

That's going to get you the newly released Albacore 2.0 with a brand new API. Check out [the wiki](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki) if you want to continue using that version and need to figure out how to make a similar call. If you want to stay on Albacore 1.0, use the pessimistic version operator to get any 1.x version.

```
gem "albacore", "~> 1.0"
```

or

```
$ gem install albacore --version "~> 1.0"
```

You're going to want to check your [CSC task specification](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/CSC), the official 1.0 release changed some properties and styles.

```
csc :build do |cmd|
  cmd.compile = FileList['MyFolder/*.cs']
  cmd.out = "F:/My.dll"
  cmd.target = :library
end
```

Based on your raw `system` calls, though, you still seem to be having trouble with some file paths or file existence. Try some `File.exist?('foo')` calls in IRB, in the same folder as your Rakefile, and see what you get.

If you're having trouble with the current working directory, every [exec-based task](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/Exec) (which, `csc` is one) inherits some extra properties, you might need to set `working_directory` to some sub-path.

```
csc :build do |cmd|
  cmd.working_directory = "foo"
  cmd.compile = FileList['MyFolder/*.cs']
  cmd.out = "F:/My.dll"
  cmd.target = :library
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [Kernel#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60):

```
Dir.chdir('/path/to/the-directory/where/you-issued-the-command')
system('csc.exe /target:library /out:F:My.dll /warn:0 /nologo /debug MyFolder/*.cs')
```

The `chdir` call is probably important in your case, as you must run the command in the same directory where you issue the command (in cmd).

Comment: Sorry, but I have errors
error CS2001: Source file '\target:library' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file '\out:F:My.dll' could not be found

Comment: @Badfishmaan, Make sure to run the command in the same directory where you issue the command (in cmd)

Comment: Yes I changed names for comfort

Comment: I tested this in cmd, and everything is OK.

Comment: @Badfishmaan, Are you using single quote (`'`) or double quote(`"`)? If you use double quote, you should escape backslash correctly.

Comment: @Badfishmaan, As previously mentioned, current working directory could be a reason. Try to change directory: `Dir.chdir('/path/to/the-directory/where/you-issued-the-command')`

Comment: I am using single quote.

Comment: I tried to change directory. And I have the same errors

Comment: @Badfishmaan, Try to pass an array instead of a big string: `system('csc.exe', '/target:library', '/out:F:My.dll', '/warn:0', '/nologo', '/debug', 'MyFolder/*.cs')`

Comment: I tried, but this code doesn`t work, error I wrote in description