# Running keystrokes from program

Tags: ruby, windows, keystrokes

I'm writing a program to automate an e-mail process and would like to know if there's a way to run keystrokes from within the program?

For example say I have this string:

```
str = "test"
```

And it gets copied to a file:

```
File.open('str.txt', 'w') { |s| s.puts(str }
```

And after that I want to use `CNTRL-A`; `CNTRL-C` on the file and copy the information, is this possible in a Ruby program, without the use of external gems?

Operating system: Windows 7

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @tadman OS is Windows 7, added to the question.

Comment: Let's backtrack a bit: am I right that what you ultimately want to do is put the contents of the string `str` into the Windows clipboard?

Comment: @nwk Basically, I know about the `gem` but I can't install it so I need a way without gems

Comment: I'm not suggesting a gem. Can you install http://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#cliptext?

Comment: @nwk Probably not, I can give it a shot though, what exactly is it

Comment: @nwk I got it installed.

Comment: It lets you copy things to the clipboard from the command line. See my answer (coming up).

Comment: Yes. If you have `clip` available on your installation of Windows, you can use it. (`clip < str.txt`)

Comment: @nwk Yeah I tired that and it tells me that the "syntax is incorrect" I like your answer though, that's pretty neat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sending arbitrary keystrokes to other applications is what you're after you can use the gem https://github.com/erinata/auto_click for it. However, if you can't use gems, what you can do instead is run [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (or one of [its](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tronautomation/) [alternatives](http://www.f2ko.de/en/cmd.php)) with the appropriate command line arguments to achieve the same result.

For example:

```
# Tell the OS to bring up the Notepad window and give it the time
# to do so.
`nircmd win activate ititle notepad`
sleep 0.5
# Select all text in the Notepad window and copy it to the
# clipboard.
`nircmd sendkeypress ctrl+a`
`nircmd sendkeypress ctrl+c`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't install gems but can copy [`ClipText.exe`](http://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#cliptext) to your current directory, do so then run this code in Ruby:

```
File.open('str.txt', 'w') { |s| s.puts(str }
`cliptext.exe from str.txt`
```

For a more rigorous way of executing commands on Windows see "[How to execute Windows CLI commands in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531498/how-to-execute-windows-cli-commands-in-ruby/7190363#7190363)".

Comment: That's a cool little tool, I highly recommend it. Works like a charm

Comment: I really like this answer, but I'm not going to accept it yet. Please don't take this as offensive, you did help me and you are a genius for this answer, I would just really like to know if there's a way to record keystrokes in Ruby, as it seems there are ways in multiple other languages.

Comment: @13aal Thanks for the generous praise! :-) What you are asking, as I understand it, just so happens to be my specialty, :-) so I have posted a separate answer explaining how to do it.